# How do you guarantee the ASPNET user gets assigned the correct default directory rights?

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio

I seem to make this mistake every time I set up a new development box. Is there a way to make sure you don't have to manually assign rights for the ASPNET user? I usually install .Net then IIS, then Visual Studio but it seems I still have to manually assign rights to the ASPNET user to get everything running correctly. Is my install order wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install IIS, then .NET.  The .NET installation will automatically register the needed things with IIS.

If you install .NET first, run this:

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regiis.exe -i
```

to run the registration parts, and

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regiis.exe -ga userA
```

to set up the security rights for userA

Answer (score 1):

If you install first IIS and then .Net, it'll be OK.

In your scenario - use [Aspnet_regiis.exe -qa *user*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h(VS.80).aspx) (not available for .Net < 2.0)